# conversion of C11 Annex K's sprintf_s to C99 snprintf

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I converted the `sprintf_s` function to C99 in this format. just wanna make sure, the results would be the same:

```
sprintf_s(char_star,"%08X",some_int);
```

the size of char_star is 8. it converts `some_int` to 8 bytes of `char_star`.

is what I did correct in C99 then? I used one of the below functions, though the output of these C99 functions and C11 Annex K `sprintf_s` is not the same

```
char str[9];
snprintf (str, 8, "%08x", i );
//      sprintf(str, "%08x", i);
QByteArray built(str, 8);
qDebug() << built.toHex();
```

in MFC it gives me this packet both with sprintf

```
30 30 30 31 30 30 44 43
```

in C99 (linux glibc) 
`sprintf(str, "%08x", i)` gives

```
30 30 30 31 30 30 64 63
```

do you know where the problem comes form?

here is the whole function:

```
bool BuildAnglePacket(char* WR_PacketAZAngle, float AZAngle)
{

    WR_PacketAZAngle[0] = 0x04;
    WR_PacketAZAngle[1] = 0x30;
    WR_PacketAZAngle[2] = 0x31;
    WR_PacketAZAngle[3] = 0x02;
    WR_PacketAZAngle[4] = 0x79;
    WR_PacketAZAngle[5] = 0x4E;
    WR_PacketAZAngle[6] = 0x48;

    int  XOR;
    char HAnlge[9];
    int iAzimuthAngle;


    if (AZAngle >= -22.5 &&  AZAngle <= 22.5 )
    {

        iAzimuthAngle = AZAngle*10;

        if( AZAngle < 0)
        {

            iAzimuthAngle= abs(iAzimuthAngle);
            iAzimuthAngle=((~iAzimuthAngle)&0xFFFF) + 1 ;
        }

        iAzimuthAngle=65536 + iAzimuthAngle;

        sprintf(HAnlge,"%08x", iAzimuthAngle);

        WR_PacketAZAngle[7]  = HAnlge[0];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[8]  = HAnlge[1];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[9]  = HAnlge[2];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[10] = HAnlge[3];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[11] = HAnlge[4];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[12] = HAnlge[5];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[13] = HAnlge[6];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[14] = HAnlge[7];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[15] = 0x03;

        for(int i=4;i<16;i++)
            XOR ^= WR_PacketAZAngle[i];

        WR_PacketAZAngle[16] = XOR;
        WR_PacketAZAngle[17] ='\x0';
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Btw, please don't call it 'linux snprintf'. `snprintf` is C99 and it's a standard.

Comment: Never use sprintf or sprintf_s unless you know what you're doing. The 'n' versions are there for your safety.

Comment: i cannot get the expected sprintf_s result using snprintf and sprintf. please clarify why I do not get the same results

Comment: please help me solve this problem

Comment: It is not clear what invocation gives you what result, but it looks like you are using "X" in one case and "x" in the other. This would explain the difference between the two results.

Comment: The function above has many flaws: it assumes the output buffer size; the content of the packet is largely undefined if the angle does not fall between a given range; the XOR local variable is not initialized => the checksum is arbitrary; why not sprint_s directly to &WR_PacketAZAngle[7] ? The 2nd argument to sprintf_s at the top of your question should be the buffer size: the output from your call to sprint_s is entirely arbitrary. You should turn on warnings in your compiler, and read, understand and fix each of them (this would have spotted your mistake right away).

Answer (score 2):

Size of `char_star` should be at least `9` to have one space to store last `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

use

sprintf_s(char_star,"%08x",some_int); 
to get the same result. The format option x and X are different!